# How to docker exec to IBM bluemix containers

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I have just started with IBM containers. Now, I want to to docker exec to the container but I found that this is not supported ([link](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_native-docker.html)).

Basically, I had put my source code in the container and now want to install it and update some configurations, For ex: update the ip address provided.

I can create an image from the installed docker container and push that to bluemix but still I need to change some configurations.

Please suggest me the alternative ways to achieve this.

Comment: Dear downvoter, I would appreciate if you can give some comments to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ssh to the IBM Container and update files as needed. 
To ssh to IBM Container you have to pass an ssh public key using the `--ssh` option.
Follow the steps below to create the ssh public/private key pair and run the IBM container:

1) Create a private/public key pair

```
# ssh-keygen -t rsa -f cloud.key
```

This will create 2 files: `cloud.key`   and `cloud.key.pub`

2) Run the IBM container passing the public key, the sample below runs the default ibmnode image (do a `cat cloud.key.pub` and paste as the ssh argument):

```
# ice run --name my-container --memory 512 --publish 8000 --ssh "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCrpMSm1U0YCvCfFZDOSqKDNZT0fd9TOWQh/jZPFWJu3BTrZuxDM0Mc5Cv6Lw0yYC5ZdqFsn4Rp4ovCkEY3JsnrE6NSsyrtxMvCGm1FDWYMJBnB4tDoWFmAULYKvdospozjk9Abvl2Hw3xu36j2c3W/x4iB/Xez0xdqNi8YN23gg8n45ZDCsDVZ4SE2ks8u81CoDcDhA3XmJF5Fpfwfnxi7OI9LNTkNJ26CnQb0/k80gYc1qUcGjgPasbWHPuPY4YJDAAr5U6faZUX8IqepLmk/icIQw+SFBQa4OS5+n4jJ3YpkM23RZdylY61t9ltU8GJI/d5tRsV7ZYeX+gE/RO53 xxxxx@xxx.yyy.com" registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode:latest
```

3) Bind a public IP address to IBM container:

```
# ice ip bind <ip-address> my-container
```

4) Run ssh command to login to the IBM Container passing private key

```
# ssh -i cloud.key root@<ip-address>
```

Comment: Do we have similar option for cf commands? I am not sure because I don't see --ssh option in the [run](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/run/) reference of docker.

Comment: I checked the documentation, I think we don't have them for cf. I'll try ice.

Comment: A more precise answer than mine. +1

Comment: I am able to ssh into the container :).Thanks. @VonC: as you approved this, I accept this as answer :).

Answer (score 1):

Since [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/run/) is supported, included with volumes, you could consider [adding a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#adding-a-data-volume).

That way, you can modify a file from the host, and the container will see the modification through the mounted volume.

Comment: Using volumes I can update the configuration but then how to restart the service withing the container? Or I'll have to restart the container?

Comment: You would either restart the container, or your service run by the container would have the necessary knowledge to monitor that configuration file and restart itself.

Comment: Service is not that intelligent :). I'll have to restart the container then. 
Can I ssh into the container?

Comment: @user3275095 don't forget that restarting a container does not mean to connect to it. Executing a command in a running container is done with `docker exec` (https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/exec/, no ssh required, that is the point). But restarting the all container means `docker stop/kill`, then `docker rm`, then `docker run`.

Comment: I agree to the point of exec but was looking ssh as an option when exec is not available. Anyways, I'll explore the volumes.

Comment: @user3275095 `docker exec` should be available for any container, as opposed to ssh.

Comment: This is going in circle :). I am just talking for the current case; IBM containers where exec is currently not supported.

Comment: @user3275095 true, I forgot the IBM context for a moment.